# evaluate simple elisp buffer in emacs without ielm mode

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I have a simple elisp script as below, which I want to run using emacs.

```
(defun add-numbers (a b)
  (+ a b))

(add-numbers 2 3)
```

Alternatively, I can goto `ielm` mode and define the function once and then call from `ELSIP` console.

I need a way to simply execute the script. I feel like there's some keys to make it execute, most probably `c-x c-e` but not being able make it work.

[image]

I get following error on `C-x C-e`, it seems a weird debugger mode though.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable a)
  eval(a nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

### Useful reference

[EvaluatingExpressions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EvaluatingExpressions)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try `C-h k C-x C-e` to rtfm.

As your cursor (the "point", in emacs terminology) is just after the symbol `a`, the last expression is `a`.

As the variable `a` is not bound, trying to evaluate it produces the message `error: (void-variable a)`.

If you really want to use `C-x C-e`, you should click just after the parenthesis closing the `defun` call and type `C-x C-e` and then move the point after the second expression and type again `C-x C-e`.

If you want to "execute the script" (in emacs terminology, we would say "evaluate the buffer"), you should type `M-x eval-buffer RET` or `Menu > Evaluate buffer`.

In this case, all the expressions contained in the buffer are evaluated, but there is no visible output: in you case, the interpreter will evaluate `(defun add-numbers (a b) (+ a b))` which will define the function `add-numbers` (with no output). Then the interpreter will evaluate the expression `(add-numbers 2 3)` which computes and returns `5`, but this does not produce any output.

Try to put in your file

```
(message "result of %s is %d" '(add-numbers 2 3) (add-numbers 2 3))
```

and `M-x eval-buffer RET` again. You should get the message in the minibuffer `result of (add-numbers 2 3) is 5`.

If you put more than one `message` in your buffer, you can see all of them with the shortcut `C-h e` (or `M-x view-echo-area-messages RET`).

Comment: Great. I got it working by `C-x C-e` twice once at function and once while invoking. But interested in `M-x eval-buffer`. It does nothing though.

Comment: When you do `M-x eval-buffer RET`, it does NOT do nothing! It evaluates the whole contents of the buffer. In your case, it defines the function `add-numbers`. You can verify this assertion using a fresh new emacs, where you try `M-: (add-numbers 1 2) RET` => you'll get an error `(void-function add-numbers)`. Maybe you'll have to quit the debugger (with the letter `q`). Then you go to your buffer and do `M-x eval-buffer RET` and try again `M-: (add-numbers 1 2) RET`. This time, you'll get the result `3` in the minibuffer, which is the proof that `eval-buffer` has defined the function!

Answer (score 1):

You want `eval-defun`, which is usually `C-M-x`.  Despite its name, what it does is look for the current top-level form and evaluate that.  'Current' is defined in some way so it does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C-M-x with the pointer (cursor) somewhere within the function code, or you can use C-x C-e, but with the pointer at the end of the function.

That means, put your pointer after the last closing parenthesis of the function definition and then press C-x C-e and then move the pointer to the end of the function call and press C-x C-e again.